# Is there a way to make GUI.SelectionGrid expand horizontally

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am working on an inventory system, And I want to be able to make a Selection Gird that expands horizontally rather than vertically, is there an easy way to do this? Or will I have to create my own version of SelectionGrid?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer 1) there is no such thing in unity (which is not that big of a surprise). However there are two methods that once can use to create a selection grid like button system. The most efficient of which (cuz GUILayout is slow) is done using plain old GUI.Functionality;

```css
for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
 for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
  if (GUI.Button (new Rect (m_BackPack.x + x*32, m_BackPack.y + y*32, 32, 32), m_EmptyInventorySlot, inventorySlotStyle)) {
   m_BackPackButton = y + x * 3;
   Debug.Log (m_BackPackButton);
    }
  }
}
```

This will create a selection grid like structure, that changes the value of m_BackPackButton to the location of the pressed button, this snippet expands horizontally, and the x,y position of any button is given by m_BackPackButton/(num horizontal buttons), m_BackPackButton%(num vertical buttons).

I think this is how selectionGrid is created internally.